# Automator - Running Node Command in AppleScript Error

Tags: automator

I am trying to run an AppleScript that runs a node command like I would run it in terminal and appear to have the right start with the code, but I'm getting hung up on Automator not recognizing the `node` command `sh: node: command not found`. Can anyone point me to the reason why automator can't locate node (node command as in Node.js. Node.js is installed on my machine)?

Here is my AppleScript:

```
do shell script "cd /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/cli && node app.js DesktopUSA"
```

Comment: Is `node` installed as part of Node.js?

Comment: @JMY1000 yes, that is correct it is for Node.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PATH variable for your AppleScript doesn't contain /usr/local/bin! You can check this with `do shell script "env >> $HOME/Desktop/env.txt"`.

So either configure an additional path or use the full path to node:

```
do shell script "cd /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/cli && /usr/local/bin/node app.js DesktopUSA"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I felt like it had to do something with telling the script where to find and access node.