# Can Node.js version be checked with AppleScript?

Tags: terminal, applescript

Starting to use Node.js more I was wondering if Node.js could actually be tested with a `do shell` but I've run into an issue. I did a search to see if this was asked but closest result was "[Automator - Running Node Command in AppleScript Error](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273205/automator-running-node-command-in-applescript-error)".

Here are my attempts:

```
tell application "System Events" to set username to name of current user
set nodePath to "/Users/" & username & "/.nvm/"
set nodeCommand to "cd " & quoted form of nodePath & " node --version"
try
    set result to do shell script nodeCommand
    return result
on error result
    return "ERROR:" & result
end try
```

my result is `""`.  Modified change to:

```
tell application "System Events" to set username to name of current user
set nodePath to "/Users/" & username & "/.nvm/"
set nodeCommand to quoted form of nodePath & " npm config list"
try
    set result to do shell script nodeCommand
    return result
on error result
    return "ERROR:" & result
end try
```

my result is `"ERROR:sh: /Users/username/.nvm/: is a directory"`.  Is there a way to check Node.js version similar to the Terminals command `npm config list` or `node -v`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have `node` installed in the directory `/usr/local/bin`, so this command will return the version:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/node -v"
```

---

A couple other scripting points:

- You needn't use *System Events* to obtain the user's username.  If all you need is the username, you can use

  ```
  short user name of (system info)
  ```
- However, it looks like you were trying to get the path to your user home folder.  In AppleScript, this can be done like so:

  ```
  POSIX path of (path to home folder)
  ```
- However, as that was all going to be plugged in to a `do shell script` command, none of that is necessary, as you can use `~` to denote your home folder, and the shell will automatically expand this for you (provided it's not inside any quotes):

  ```
  do shell script "cd ~/.nvm/"
  ```
- There's no need to `set result to`.  `result` will automatically contain the result of the previous AppleScript command.  `return result` will work fine without needing to `set result to`.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you're having trouble with a set of code, try to create the simplest possible test case so you can be sure where the bug is.

I created a one line applescript:

```
set nodeVersion to do shell script "node --version"
```

This does indeed fail to work. Applescript says: `error "sh: node: command not found" number 127`

So the problem is that for some reason, sh can't find the node binary when run via Applescript. So I decided to try specifying the full path:

```
set nodeVersion to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/node --version"
```

It worked! Not sure why this is necessary, but it should fix the problem.

(Your path will likely be the same as mine, but if the above still doesn't work, try running `which node` in a terminal window to find what path you need.)